# IE showing 2 footers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, footer

http://dev.madhousecreative.co.uk/ptc1.php

The following problem only occurs on IE on a few pages of my site under this portfolio section in the link.

the offending code seems to be:

```
<ul id="list-nav">
<li><a href="portal-tax-claims.php">Previous</a></li>
<li><a href="portal-tax-claims.php">1</a></li>
<li><a href="" style="color:#BB2131;">2</a></li>
<li><a href="ptc2.php">3</a></li>
<li><a href="ptc3.php">4</a></li>
<li><a href="ptc2.php">Next</li>
</ul>
```

When I take that out it seems to work. But I need that in there. It seems to be fine in all other browsers. How can I fix this/what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed closing a tag and that might cause the problem:

```
<li><a href="ptc2.php">Next</a></li>
```

Comment: Close tag appears to be there on the live link. I think this might just be a typo from the OP